# Abstract Binary Search

Tags: binary-search

In the article http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binarySearch,
he says

> Careful readers may note that binary search can also be used when a
>   predicate yields a series of `yes` answers followed by a series of `no`
>   answers. This is true and complementing that predicate will satisfy
>   the original condition. For simplicity we'll deal only with predicates
>   described in the theorem.

I couldn't get what he meant could some one please explain?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know what a predicate is?

Comment: i assume something question which results in a yes or no answer

Comment: I think this explanation requires that you have a stronger background in formal logic. Learn your p's and q's!

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you're doing a binary search on a set of numbers: for the search to work, you need to put the numbers in order, so that the question "*is this number less than the number I'm searching for*" gives yeses followed by nos.

Example: searching for number 8 in the sequence [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]

- is 1 less than 8 ? "yes"
- is 1 less than 8 ? "yes"
- is 2 less than 8 ? "yes"
- is 3 less than 8 ? "yes"
- is 5 less than 8 ? "yes"
- is 8 less than 8 ? "no"
- is 13 less than 8 ? "no"
- is 21 less than 8 ? "no"

This means if you looked at, say the middle number in the sequence, you could tell instantly whether your target number was before or after this mid-point (if you get a 'no' look before, if you get a 'yes' look after). You can then exclude the unwanted half of the series and repeat the process with the remaining half...

This way of halving the search field at each step is the key to binary search, and guarantees you will find the target in O(log n) time.

Looking at the second part of your paragraph:

> `complementing that predicate will satisfy the original condition`

To `complement the predicate` means to swap 'yes' and 'no', which would give us 'a series of no answers followed by a series of yes answers', which is referred to in the previous paragraph (the `original condition`).

So in summary, your quote is saying **'yes followed by no' will work equally as well as 'no followed by yes'**

Answer (score 0):

He is talking about formal logic, and using terms from formal logic.

Directly from the article:

"Behind the cryptic mathematics I am really stating that if you had a yes or no question (the predicate), getting a yes answer for some potential solution x means that you'd also get a yes answer for any element after x. Similarly, if you got a no answer, you'd get a no answer for any element before x. As a consequence, if you were to ask the question for each element in the search space (in order), you would get a series of no answers followed by a series of yes answers."

I think you're going to need to use some elbow grease and buff up on those terms. I'm not sure which part you're having trouble with.

Comment: oh i got it..i was confusing it with something else..Thanks